# Firebase on PlatformException Error Not working

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a `try .. catch` block when loggin in or signing up with `FirebaseAuth.instance`

This is the code that I have.

```
 try {
   //... code here
} on PlatformException catch (err) {
  var message = 'An error occured, please check your credentials.';

  if (err.message != null) {
    message = err.message!;
  }

  ScaffoldMessenger.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(ctx).errorColor,
    ),
  );
  // other codes here

} catch (err) {
  print(err);
}
```

The problem now is that if I'm encountering an error like `The email address is badly formatted.`  or `he email address is already in use by another account`, this is not going inside the `on PlatformException catch (err)`  block and its goin in the `catch` block instead.

How can I make sure that the types of errors I mentioned above should be executed in the `on PlatformException` block?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this hope you'll get the solution!

```
   try {
       //... code here
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      String errorMessage = AuthExceptionHandler.handleException(e);
      errorSnackBar(content: errorMessage);
    } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
    }
```

AuthExceptionHandler class for managing error message according error code.

```
class AuthExceptionHandler {
  static handleException(e) {
    AuthResultStatus status;
    switch (e.code) {
      case "invalid-email":
        status = AuthResultStatus.invalidEmail;
        break;
      case "wrong-password":
        status = AuthResultStatus.wrongPassword;
        break;
      case "user-not-found":
        status = AuthResultStatus.userNotFound;
        break;
      case "user-disabled":
        status = AuthResultStatus.userDisabled;
        break;
      case "too-many-requests":
        status = AuthResultStatus.tooManyRequests;
        break;
      case "operation-not-allowed":
        status = AuthResultStatus.operationNotAllowed;
        break;
      case "email-already-in-use":
        status = AuthResultStatus.emailAlreadyExists;
        break;
      default:
        status = AuthResultStatus.undefined;
    }
    return generateExceptionMessage(status);
  }

  ///
  /// Accepts AuthExceptionHandler.errorType and set message according error
  static generateExceptionMessage(exceptionCode) {
    String errorMessage;
    switch (exceptionCode) {
      case AuthResultStatus.invalidEmail:
        errorMessage = StringConstants.emailAddressMalformed.tr;
        break;
      case AuthResultStatus.wrongPassword:
        errorMessage = StringConstants.wrongPassword.tr;
        break;
      case AuthResultStatus.userNotFound:
        errorMessage = StringConstants.userNotExist.tr;
        break;
      case AuthResultStatus.userDisabled:
        errorMessage = StringConstants.userDisable.tr;
        break;
      case AuthResultStatus.tooManyRequests:
        errorMessage = StringConstants.manyRequestTryAfterSomeTime.tr;
        break;
      case AuthResultStatus.operationNotAllowed:
        errorMessage = StringConstants.signInNotEnable.tr;
        break;
      case AuthResultStatus.emailAlreadyExists:
        errorMessage = StringConstants.emailAlreadyExist.tr;
        break;
      default:
        errorMessage = StringConstants.undefinedErrorHappened.tr;
    }

    return errorMessage;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright! I have resolved it by using `on FirebaseAuthException` instead of `on PlatformException`. Hopefully this will help others who will be experiencing the same problem in the future.

Comment: Good you figure this out.  Also see the episode of the Boring Show we did on the topic: https://youtu.be/Gz0x77Hd1GE?t=2872